# jqtransform & Position Absolutes's jQuery-Validation-Engine: Is it possible?

Tags: jquery, validation, jqtransform

I am using jqtransform on my forms for a site. I am also using the inline validation plugin found here: http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/

Validation works great except for `<select>` menus. I want to make it so that they can't select the first option. So I set it's first option to `<option value="">Please Make A Selection</option>`

When I select it, it doesn't register that it is required. I know this is because jqtransform turns the `<select>` menu into an unordered list.

Is there any way to get these two plugins to work together?

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully been able to use these two plugins together.  Although, never on a  element.  However, you may be able to create a rule for the jquery validation engine such that the value of the  cannot be `Please Make A Selection`.  If it is, then the jquery validation engine would throw and error.  You can do this by creating a new regex rule, or by utilizing the funcCall class in your element.

Answer (score 0):

Use below css code as inline where jquery validation engine and JQTransform plugin applied together:-

style="display:block !important;height:0px !important; border: 0px !important"